# BASH Script - SubMenu and Nested case

Tags: bash, menu, scripting, switch-statement, submenu

I'm pretty new in Bash scripting, and i'm facing to this issue.

```
echo "Which version of the product ?"
echo "1. v3.0"
echo "2. v2.0"
echo "3. v1.0"
read -p "Select the version needed [ 1 - 3 ] : " SelectMajorVersion
clear

case $SelectMajorVersion in
1) PACKAGE_URL="URL" ;;
2) echo "1. 2.1.0"
   echo "2. 2.1.1"
   echo "3. 2.1.2"
   echo "4. 2.1.3"
   echo "5. 2.1.4"
   read -p "Select the version needed [ 1 - 5 ] : " SelectMinorVersion
   case $SelectMinorVersion in
        1) PACKAGE_URL="URL1" ;;
        2) PACKAGE_URL="URL2" ;;
        3) PACKAGE_URL="URL3" ;;
        4) PACKAGE_URL="URL4" ;;
        5) PACKAGE_URL="URL5" ;;
        *) printf -e "${RED}Error...${NC}\n" && sleep 2 ;;
    esac

3) echo "1. 1.5.0"
   echo "2. 1.5.1"
   echo "3. 1.5.2"
   echo "4. 1.5.3"
   read -p "Select the version needed [ 1 - 8 ] : " SelectMinorVersion
   case $SelectMinorVersion in
        1) PACKAGE_URL="URL11" ;;
        2) PACKAGE_URL="URL22" ;;
        3) PACKAGE_URL="URL33" ;;
        4) PACKAGE_URL="URL44" ;;

*) printf -e "${RED}Error...${NC}\n" && sleep 2 ;;
   esac
esac
```

This is the error message after selecting a "major" version :

```
./menu3.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./menu3.sh: line 27: `    3)  echo "1. 1.5.0"'
```

The issue seem to be related just before "3) echo "1. 1.5.0" with the "esac".

Step taken :
- I cannot see anything with Visual Studio, however the color syntax is different with VIM. So if remove the "esac" or add "case" before the line "3) echo 1.5.0", the syntax color is again "normal" in Vim.

- If I run the script without the 3rd case/esac, it works perfectly.
- It seem the esac line 25 close the first esac instead the second (!?)

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Take a look at: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to finish each case with `;;`

Here, you're not finishing the case 2)

```
2)
    ...
    esac
;;
3) echo "1. 1.5.0"
...
```